# Position fixed related parent container

Tags: javascript, css

I need solution to emulate fixed position, but relative parent div, not whole viewport. JS solutions are laggy. I need fixed related parent container, because if window has small height, div with fixed position enters into footer zone.

[Example](http://binitex.com/jet/20101112-7i8-23kb.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach re your update.

Try giving the fixed `div` `z-index: 10;`

And the footer div `position: relative; z-index: 11`

That should make the footer overlap the fixed div.

Comment: Hm, it's good solution, but i wanted to stop scroll of widget near footer.

Comment: @INs definitely not possible without Javascript.

Comment: maybe you know good JS solution with smooth scrolling, as fixed position? jquery plugin scrollfollow is laggy.

Comment: @INs Scrollfollow would have been the only recommendation I know, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

then it's not an issue of position:fixed, maybe you could just define a min-height to your body (or on the main wrapper if any) to avoid the short page problem

Comment: I have added example what i mean

Answer (score 0):

I have combined css and js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var $sidebar = $(".register-box"),
                $window = $(window),
                $content = $("#content"),
                docHeight = $(document).height();
                var entered = false;

                $window.scroll(function () {
                    if ($window.height() < 795 && docHeight - $window.scrollTop() < 785) {
                        entered = true;
                        var pos = $sidebar.offset();
                        $sidebar.css('position', 'absolute').css('top', ($content.height() - ($sidebar.height() + 40)) + 'px');
                    }
                    else {
                        if (entered) {
                            entered = false;
                            $sidebar.css({
                                top: "",
                                left: "",
                                position: "fixed"
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Code is not final, and numbers are hard coded, but it works, smooth enough.